# How to make MVC Html.EditorFor ignore Form values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view for processing a credit card transaction. It uses a simple model containing a CreditCardNumber property. If there are errors I blank out the CreditCardNumber property on the model.  The problem is that MVC goes ahead and fills in the CreditCardNumber. I am guessing it is looking at the posted form values and is trying to helpfully fill it back in for me.  I don't want this.

How can I make MVC's Html.EditorFor not use the posted form values and use my model's property value exclusively?

Comment: What does your controller return on a failed request?

Comment: An otherwise fully populate model

Answer (score 1):

It should work correctly if you explicitly pass the edited model to the View call.

```
public ActionResult BuyNow(BuyNowViewModel vm)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
      vm.CreditCardNumber = null;
      return View(vm);
  }
}
```

Comment: But you'll only want to do this if `!ModelState.IsValid` right?

Comment: Right.  Or some other non-standard validation code fails somewhere (one never knows, thanks for the suggestion).

Comment: This is exactly what I am already doing. The model does not contain the CreditCardNumber when its passed to the view

Comment: You might need to post some code in order to troubleshoot this issue, because what you're describing isn't normal.

Answer (score 0):

Your View is checking your ModelState first, then your ViewModel.  So if you manually change values, you need to clear your ModelState.

ModelState.Clear();

Useful blog on the subject: http://balawinwin.wordpress.com/2012/11/24/asp-net-mvcs-html-helpers-ignoring-model-changes/